# Installing Browsermob proxy for getting HTTP codes

Tags: python, proxy, browsermob-proxy

I might seem naive while asking this. I need to retrieve various HTTP codes, for few of our test scenarios. Now I know that Selenium cannot do it alone and we have to use a third party resource- may be a proxy like Browsermob.

Has any one already worked on this. I have gone through various tutorials -like one from [here](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py) but I can't seem to be able to work around using this.

I installed Browsermob using the `pip` method and so I am giving the path as

```
  from browsermobproxy import Server
  server = Server('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/browsermobproxy')
```

However, I am receiving the exception

```
  Exception: Browsermob-Proxy binary couldn't be found in path provided: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/browsermobproxy
```

My question is - is there anything- any file that I might be missing here? Do I need to download any other files or my path is incorrect?

Answer (score 8):

I was a bit confused about this when starting too, but I'm assuming you installed the browsermobproxy package using pip. You also need to actually download the browsermob-proxy binary (available here: https://bmp.lightbody.net/), then point to *it* from within your python script.

I was using a virtual environment so I put it here:

```
/Users/username/Envs/ScrapeProj/bin/browsermob-proxy-2.1.2/bin/browsermob-proxy
```

If you get the error message:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
```

Run these commands in the Terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you understand browsermob-proxy-py , it's a client implementation instead of server. so you need to install the server browsermob-proxy first(https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) and run the proxy with default port.

Answer (score 0):

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794746/what-should-be-the-path-of-browsermob-proxy-when-installed-as-pypi-package/66219260#66219260)

Double check your path, vars, installations, etc

You can also try to add the actual directory to the PATH

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This way you don't have to specify the path arg on the Server instance manually

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
server = Server()
```