# What should be the path of browsermob-proxy when installed as pypi package

Tags: python, python-3.x, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

$`pip install browsermob-proxy`

Downloaded and extracted the binary from https://bmp.lightbody.net to `/Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/`

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
dict = {'port': 8090}
server = Server(options=dict)
server = Server(path="/Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy", options=dict)
```

> Browsermob-Proxy binary couldn't be found in path
>   provided: browsermob-proxy

Following:
https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py

$ `ls -l "/Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin"`

```
total 16
-rwxr--r--@ 1 ishandutta2007  staff   781B Dec 26  2016 browsermob-proxy*
-rwxr--r--@ 1 ishandutta2007  staff   2.7K Dec 24  2016 browsermob-proxy.bat*
drwxrwxr-x@ 3 ishandutta2007  staff   102B Sep  5 01:07 conf/
```

$ `ls -l "/Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy"`

```
-rwxr--r--@ 1 ishandutta2007  staff   781B Dec 26  2016 /Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy*
```

Comment: overriding built-in dict doesn't look like a good idea

Comment: can you post output of `ls -l "/Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy"`?

Comment: @Marat updated the question as per your ask

Comment: I wanted to make sure the binary is readable and executable by you, and it is. Do you run it from under your account?

Comment: after your comment tried `chmod 777 full/path/to/file` but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the actual directory to the PATH

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This way you don't have to specify the path arg on the Server instance manually

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
dict = {'port': 8090}
server = Server(options=dict)
```