# Getting error 'Browsermob-Proxy binary couldn't be found in path provided' even after installing required proxy

Tags: python, proxy, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

I am using a Mac and installed the required files from bmp.lightbody.net, and unzipped them. I tried creating a Server in my Python file using the following code.

`server = Server('/Users/username/Downloads/⁨browsermob-proxy-2.1.4⁩/bin⁩/browsermob-proxy')`

I was met with the following error

```
browsermobproxy.exceptions.ProxyServerError: Browsermob-Proxy binary couldn't be found in path provided: /Users/username/Downloads/⁨browsermob-proxy-2.1.4⁩/bin⁩/browsermob-proxy
```

The path runs perfectly in my Terminal, and I was able to create a proxy.

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/proxy
{"port":8081}
```

I have also tried appending the folder to my path using `sys` and moving the browsermob folder to the folder where the python file is present, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794746/what-should-be-the-path-of-browsermob-proxy-when-installed-as-pypi-package/66219260#66219260)

Try to add the actual directory to the PATH

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Downloads/⁨browsermob-proxy-2.1.4⁩/bin⁩' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This way you don't have to specify the path arg on the Server instance manually

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
dict = {'port': 8090}
server = Server(options=dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows, here what worked for me:

- Download the release ZIP file from: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/releases
- Extract to a folder
- Call it in the code like that:

```py
import requests
from browsermobproxy import Server
import time

# Start the BrowserMob Proxy server
server = Server(r"D:\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\bin\browsermob-proxy.bat")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
```